# What is the equivalent of Image.AFFINE for torch tensor inputs

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am wondering how to rewrite Image.AFFINE to work for torch tensor.

Here is the code:

```
            frame = torch.load(file_path + '/' + f)            
            offset += random.randrange(-v, v)
            offset = min(offset, 3 * v)
            offset = max(offset, -3 * v)
            frame = frame.transform(frame.size, Image.AFFINE, (1, 0, offset, 0, 1, 0))
            if self.transform is not None:
                frame = self.transform[0](frame)
            frames.append(frame)
```